# Error in neural network training with neuralnet package in R

Tags: r, neural-network

Noob here. Apologies in advance if I don't clearly state the problem.

I am trying to train a neural network with fake weights and heights of males and females to obtain the probability of sex only based in kg and cm,  but I am encountering errors in neuralnet() or train() functions that I can not resolve. Most of the time the error is:

```
Error in x[0, , drop = FALSE] : número incorreto de dimensiones
```

Here is a example code of one of my attempts:

```
set.seed(123)
library(neuralnet)
library(caret)

# data1: training data
sex <- factor(sample(c("male", "female"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
height <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(1.8, 1.6)[sex])
weight <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(80, 60)[sex])
data1 <- data.frame(sex, height, weight)

# data2: population data
sex <- factor(sample(c("male", "female"), size = 10000, replace = TRUE))
height <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(1.81, 1.61)[sex])
weight <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(81, 61)[sex])
data2 <- data.frame(sex, height, weight)

# training 

net  <- neuralnet(sex ~ height + weight, 
                  data = data1, hidden = c(10, 10), 
                  linear.output = FALSE, 
                  threshold = 0.1, stepmax = 10000)

trained_net <- train(net, data, error.fun = "ce", stepmax = 1e+07)

# Prediction and results

predictions <- compute(trained_net, data2[, c("height", "weight")])
predictions_df <- data.frame(predictions$net.result)
colnames(predictions_df) <- c("probfemale")
result <- cbind(datos2, predictions_df)
                  result$prediccion_sex <- ifelse(resul$probfemale >= 0.5, "female", "male")
```

I am aware that human weights and heights of males and females overlap enough in real world to make a good prediction, but this is not the goal at all, but obtain some  prediction of whatever factor based in whatever two numeric variables, without being stopped by fatal errors about incorrect dimensions or lack of convergence. My  goal now is just reach some result, no matter if it is less reliable than a politician's promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to combine two packages (frameworks)  `caret` and `neuralnet` that wont play together out of the box.

### data creation:

```
set.seed(123)

# data1: training data
sex <- factor(sample(c("male", "female"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
height <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(1.8, 1.6)[sex])
weight <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(80, 60)[sex])
data1 <- data.frame(sex, height, weight)

# data2: population data
sex <- factor(sample(c("male", "female"), size = 10000, replace = TRUE))
height <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(1.81, 1.61)[sex])
weight <- rnorm(1000, mean = c(81, 61)[sex])
data2 <- data.frame(sex, height, weight)
```

### Option 1 Using library `neuralnet`:

```
library(neuralnet)

# training using library: neuralnet

net  <- neuralnet(sex ~ height + weight, 
                  data = data1, hidden = c(10, 10), 
                  linear.output = FALSE, 
                  threshold = 0.1, stepmax = 10000)

# prediction using library: neuralnet
predictions_nn <- predict(net,data2[-1])
# convert to dataframe
predictions_nn <- as.data.frame(predictions_nn) 
# create sex factor from prediction probabilities
predictions_nn$sex <- factor(ifelse(predictions_nn[1] < predictions_nn[2],"male","female"))

> head(predictions_nn$sex)

[1] male   female female female female male  
Levels: female male
```

#### Option 2: using `caret`

```
library(caret)
# training nnet using caret
trained_net <- train(y=data1$sex,x=data1[-1] ,method = 'nnet',stepmax = 1e+05)

# prediction nnet using caret
predictions_nnet <- predict(trained_net,data2[-1])

> head(predictions_nnet)

[1] male   female female female female male  
Levels: female male
```

### comparison:

```
> all(predictions_nn$sex==predictions_nnet)
[1] TRUE
```

the give the same predictions.

Comment: Nice. Only two things: (1) In spite that `train()` is passed to `trained_net` print several pages of weight. How I can hide this? (2) It is possible with neuralnet and/or  caret not only make the prediction but also the probability of be true ? Accepted and upvoted anyway. Thanks.

Comment: regarding 1: use `trace=FALSE` to hide the messages. regarding 2: for `neuralnet` it already reports probs (look at the object) for `caret` use `type="prob"`  in the predict function.